# React Firebase deleting the wrong document id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, material-ui

I've been trying to make a delete operation on a firebase database using Reactjs. I've got a bug with my function grabbing the wrong id from firebase.

I have a button that calls a *handleOpen* function which opens a Modal.

**Modal operations:**

```
// Grabs the right id
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const handleOpen = (id) => {
    console.log(id); 
    setOpen(true);
  };
  const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);
```

I've got a button that calls a *handleDelete* function which grabs the document id reference and deletes the document reference.

**handleDelete function:**

```
const handleDelete = (id) => {
    const docRef = projectFirestore.collection("News").doc(id);
    docRef.delete();
    console.log("Deleted post data from id: " + id);
    handleClose();
  };
```

**The Problem**

From what I've been watching the handleDelete function grabs the last id from the mapped array of posts, it doesn't pass the id of the current document to the modal.

*The problem only happens when I pass the function inside the modal. When I pass the function outside of the modal it works just fine.*

**The Objective**

Grabbing document id, passing it to the modal and deleting the respective document.

Here's the full code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { projectFirestore } from "../../../../firebase/config";
import { useCollectionData } from "react-firebase-hooks/firestore";
import Layout from "../../../../hoc/Layout/Layout";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Button, Box, Modal } from "@mui/material";

const DeletePost = () => {
  const docRef = projectFirestore.collection("News");
  const query = docRef.orderBy("createdAt", "desc");
  const [posts] = useCollectionData(query, { idField: "id" });

  // Modal operations
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const handleOpen = (id) => {
    setOpen(true);
  };
  const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);

  const handleDelete = (id) => {
    const docRef = projectFirestore.collection("News").doc(id);
    docRef.delete();
    console.log("Deleted post data from id: " + id);
    handleClose();
  };
  return (
    <Layout>
      <ul>
        {posts &&
          posts.map((post) => {
            const data = post.createdAt.toDate();
            const day = data.getUTCDate();
            const month = data.getUTCMonth();
            const year = data.getUTCFullYear();
            return (
              <li key={post.id}>
                <div>
                  <h3>{post.id}</h3>
                  <img
                    src={post.url}
                    alt={post.title}
                  />
                  <p>
                    <b>
                      {day}/{month}/{year}
                    </b>{" "}
                    {post.description}
                  </p>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <Link to="/edit-post">
                    <Button>
                      Edit Post
                    </Button>
                  </Link>
                  <Button onClick={() => handleOpen()}>
                    Delete Post
                  </Button>
                  <Modal
                    open={open}
                    onClose={handleClose}
                    aria-labelledby="Delete"
                    aria-describedby="Delete Post"
                  >
                    <Box>
                      <div>
                        <h4>
                          Are you sure you want to delete {post.title}?
                        </h4>
                      </div>

                      <div>
                        <Button
                          onClick={() => {
                            debugger;
                            handleDelete(post.id);
                          }}
                        >
                          Yes
                        </Button>
                        <Button onClick={handleClose}>
                          No
                        </Button>
                      </div>
                    </Box>
                  </Modal>
                </div>
              </li>
            );
          })}
      </ul>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default DeletePost;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a state variable that keeps tracks of the currently editing ID:

```
const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState(-1);
```

Then edit your `handleOpen` and `handleClose` functions:

```
  const handleOpen = (id) => {
    setSelectedId(id);
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setSelectedId(-1);
    setOpen(false);
  };
```

In the `handleDelete` function, if an ID is selected, delete that one:

```
  const handleDelete = (id) => {
    const docRef = projectFirestore.collection('News').doc(selectedId !== -1 ? selectedId : id);
    docRef.delete();
    console.log('Deleted post data from id: ' + id);
    handleClose();
  };
```

Finally, you will need to update the `handleOpen` method in the JSX by adding the id parameter:

```
<Button onClick={() => handleOpen(post.id)}>
    Delete Post
</Button>
```

Comment: That was a good way of approaching the problem. I also passed the value of the selectedId to the handleDelete and it worked very nicely!

Answer (score 0):

This simple functionality works with `Firebase 10`.

```
const deleteHandler = async (userId: string) => {
    await deleteDoc(doc(db, 'collection_name', userId));
}
```

and in template:

```
<Button onClick={() => deleteHandler(id)}>
    Delete Item
</Button>
```

Use [deleteDoc()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data) method.